# php storm customize docblock

Tags: phpstorm, docblocks

Is there a way to customize php storm's way of generating the docblocks ?

By default, I would like to have unknown type vars considered as strings.

This is the default way of generating docblock
(using php storm 4.01)

```
/**
 * @param $name
 */
private function test($name){

}
```

And I would like this instead if possible :

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 */
private function test($name){

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, you cannot provide default type for generated @param.

PhpStorm provides correct type whenever it is possible to detect from function declaration. In your example it is not possible (it can be anything).

And I *personally* do not see a real reason why it needs to be a string (or any other type) *by default*. Unknown/missing type tells me that I need to finish editing this PHPDoc block so it reflects the actual/correct parameter type. With default type entered already such check is not possible (what if the type should be some class (e.g. Person) or array instead?)

**P.S.**
Kind of related (at least to the actual subject):

This is the Feature Request ticket for *Editable PHPDoc Template* (that can define what @tags and in what order should be used): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11111

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The reason why I would need this is gain some time.
If string is already typed, I can fix it quickly when it is wrong by double clicking on it.
It may seem a very little gain of time, but there are a lot of methods to comment so I would appreciate
even that tiny save. Further more, php storm already recognizes the object type as they appear in the declaration
(in my case), I also use the array keyword when I'm using an array. So finally, it could just be one of string or int.
Hope they'll implement this feature some day.